# How one can use 'Wide-angle lense' or 'Telephoto lense' using camera2 api?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

As per my understanding `manager.getCameraIdList()` returns the possible number of logical camera id's we can use.Is there any way to determine which camera Id is an Id for 'Wide-angle lense' or 'Telephoto-lense' using `manager.getCameraCharacteristics()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS). If the cameras don't have optical zoom, then the numbers they will provide can straightforwardly  be used to tell the difference between a wide-angle lens(low number) and a telephoto lens(high number).